# I get ssl error when making a request to a non ssl API in htpclient in .net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, httpclient, asp.net-core-5.0

**Controller:**

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"api/v1/muayenedurum/takip-no/{takipNo}");

                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("server");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using var Response = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                }
```

**Startup :**

```
    services.AddHttpClient("server", c =>
                {
                    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.websiteaddress.com");
                }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                    return handler;
                });
```

**Error:**

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync(TIOAdapter adapter)

HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(bool async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Can you help with this ?

Comment: Why are you adding a `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` when the request is `http` (no SSL) and not `https` (SSL)? The client will try to negotiate a server certificate but will fail since the server is not serving one.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Remove the configuration for the primary http message handler. Since you're not using SSL it is not necessary.

Comment: I solved the problem by getting ssl certificate.